# Using 'max()' in expression with QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, expression, rule-based, maximum

I want to make a rule-based style on the maximum value from a field. I set my expression like:

```
max("fieldname")
```

It returns every value instead of only the maximum one.

Can anyone tell me the right syntax for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since QGIS 2.16 there is now an inbuilt way to calculate the maximum value for a whole layer with the [`maximum`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#maximum) function:

```
maximum("fieldname")
```

This will return the largest value in the `"fieldname"` column for the layer.

Comment: How could I show name of maximum value from other column? If I have field "Covid-19" how to show name of the city of maximum value?  maximum("covid-19") then show name of city

Answer (score 6):

The [`max`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#max) function doesn't operate across features, just values passed to the function. E.g.

```
max(1,5,3)
```

Will return 5. There's no function currently available which calculates the maximum value for an attribute across the entire layer.

Comment: I have a feeling that there must be a function for this available meanwhile ;)

Answer (score 2):

This code, in Python Console of QGIS, returns maximum value of field whose index is 3: `"AREA"` (shapefile used: [world_borders.zip](https://db.tt/9LWKpOjm)):

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
id_att_list = layer.pendingAllAttributesList()

print id_att_list #list of attributes index

for item in id_att_list:
    #index and field names
    print item,layer.attributeDisplayName(item)

#maximum value for field whose index is 3 (AREA)
area_max = layer.maximumValue(3)

print "maximum area = ", area_max
```

[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with python.  How do I implement this into the rule-based-style?